# Prefill Google Forms with current date by manipulating p refill url string

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-forms

Hello  I have research many ways on how to prefill google form with a current date in the date input field.
The best i came up with is to create a prefill form and use the prefill google form url and dynamically change the url string to insert current date as one of the arguments.
I tried creating a page(google app script)  with a link reference that i am trying to set the link href to the new string containing current date argument but no success. I already have a function(in code.gs) that take the google form url and manipulates it correctly to input the current date in the url string as one of the arguments. But setting this new url string in the link href  not working.

Can you advise(examples be great) on this or an easier way to prefill current date on a google form.
Most most appreciated.

```
/* NOTE!!! Make a copy of this file - Choose "File" "Make a copy..."
 * Then publish this as a Web App - 
 * To Publish Choose the menu item "Publish" then "Deploy as Web App"
 * to see the Web App click the link named - "Test web app for your latest code"
 *
 */

var EXAMPLE_OF_GLOBAL_VARIABLE;//Use all capital letters so that you know it is a global
var n3;
function doGet() {
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');


// Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
return template.evaluate()
  .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
 .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  };

  //Attribute - This code is modified from the Google Help for a web app
    //Help - Welcome Screen - Web App
 function getFolderContents() {
 var contents,file,files,folderId,numFiles,topFolder;

 folderId = 'root'; //Set this as the default for an example
 topFolder;
 contents = {
  children: []
  };

 if (folderId == 'root') {
topFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
} else {
// May throw exception if the folderId is invalid or app
// doesn't have permission to access.
topFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
}
contents.rootName = topFolder.getName() + '/';

 files = topFolder.getFiles();
 numFiles = 0;

while (files.hasNext() && numFiles < 20) {
file = files.next();
contents.children.push(file.getName());
numFiles++;
};

return contents; 
 };
function getnowx() {
var today = new Date();
 var dd = today.getDate();
 var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
      dd = '0'+dd
      } ;
    if(mm<10) {
      mm = '0'+mm
      }; 
   today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  var n ='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5By6kDoO_T4WZWk5VjKs6WD5RVuC_06RX7jDv19jS-KR8sg/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1374707830=xxxx-xx-xx&entry.406706983&entry.1232084117&entry.769389513&entry.104847992';
     var n1 = n.replace("xxxx-xx-xx",today);  
      return n1;
       };
```

my javascript section

```
 <script>
     function updateDisplay(contents) {
     var headingText = "Displaying contents for " + contents.rootName + " 
    folder:";
     document.getElementById('main-heading').textContent = headingText;
     for (var i = 0; i < contents.children.length; i++) {
     var name = contents.children[i];
  document.getElementById('results').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div>' 
  + name + '</div>');

   }

  function updateDisplay2(n5) {

   var linkButton = document.getElementById("link-button");
   linkButton.setAttribute('href', n5); 
   document.getElementById('link-button').textContent = linkText;
   }

  window.getTheData = function() {
  google.script.run
   .withSuccessHandler(updateDisplay)
  .getFolderContents();

    };

  window.getnowx2 = function() {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(updateDisplay2)
  .getnowx();
  }
   </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the `url` and also snapshot of `code.gs`

Comment: I copied a piece of online code and modifying it.

Comment: how do i add a snap shot to this this forum ?

Comment: trying added it here but error on text too long

Comment: Edit the question to add it

Comment: this is my function with url embedded in it . Have it in code.gs

Comment: function getnowx() {
   var today = new Date();
     var dd = today.getDate();
     var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
     var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    
    if(dd<10) {
          dd = '0'+dd
          } ;
        if(mm<10) {
          mm = '0'+mm
          }; 
       today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
      var n =

Comment: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5By6kDoO_T4WZWk5VjKs6WD5RVuC_06RX7jDv19jS-KR8sg/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1374707830=xxxx-xx-xx&entry.406706983&entry.1232084117&entry.769389513&entry.104847992';
     var n1 = n.replace("xxxx-xx-xx",today);  
    return n1;
   };

Comment: If you add that code to your question, it would be more readable.

Comment: Hey, I edited your question. I think it should return the right url for you now. Not sure if you are using it the right way.

Comment: I see `Ardis Transactions` form with the right date filled.

Comment: I am seeing where you made the edit. The getnowx function works when tested.

Comment: It when i am in the index html my set link atribute does not work. Not getting the value passed from getnowx

Comment: Can you post the set link attribute code as well?

Comment: just did........

Comment: ok need to leave now . Will check back tomorrow, I am new to GAS so they may be better/easier ways to do this. Looking forward to suggestions .

Comment: Tried the recommendation did not work. My index.html file all garbled up because i tried so many experiments on it. Going to take a break for a few days from this(frustration).

Comment: Basically i  can create the prefill url form string correctely. But because of my lack of experience with GAS i an unable to open this url string from a the variable i created to publish to my index.html file. If you can point to examples of how to publish a anchor link using a variable to an index file or other method  to open internet page based on my url variable i will appreciate. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing it from

```
window.getnowx2 = function() {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(updateDisplay2)
  .getnowx();
  }
```

to

```
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(updateDisplay2)
  .getnowx();
```

The reason being in the first statement you are assigning a function to a variable 
`window.getnowx2` but not calling it. In the second statement you would actually call it.
Sorry, I'm not too sure of this though, someone more knowledgeable will address this if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Per Chance came across some code in stack exchange and it worked. Very simple just did not know how. My getnow function take prefill form url and string manipulate to insert current date so i can get a google form with current date automatically.

```
function doGet() {
    var url = getnowx();
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
   "<a href='" + url + "?page=1'>Mylabel</a> <br><a href='" + url + "?
    page=1'>MyLABEL2</a>");

    };


function getnowx() {
   var today = new Date();
     var dd = today.getDate();
     var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
     var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
          dd = '0'+dd
          } ;
        if(mm<10) {
          mm = '0'+mm
          }; 
       today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
      var n = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5BykDoO_T4WZWk5VjKs6WD5xxC_06RX7jDv19jS-KvR8sg/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1374707830=xxxx-xx-xx&entry.406706983&entry.1232084117&entry.769389513&entry.104847992';
     var n1 = n.replace("xxxx-xx-xx",today);  
    return n1;
   };
```